# posting with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp-classic

I am pretty new new to Ajax and Jquery and trying tunderstand it. Well, I want to submit to the same page and then read the values.

I have something likes this which does not seem to work:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin_fans.asp",                
                data: {
                    "IDCollection": sMemberIDCollection,
                    "task": "addnewmember"
                }
            })
```

and I am trying to read it on the page with something like this

```
if (Request("task")="") Then
    response.Write("after form submit")
    response.End()
End if
```

It does nothing. It is classic ASp by the way

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a semicolon on your last line.

```
}) to });
```

Comment: Oh yes added semicolon. But I think code has some more problems as well as noted. BUT no tutorial shows how to read it in simple manner after POST is complete and i want to read this data from ASP code then what should I do?

Comment: I haven't tedted this using POST, but I think you if reformat your JavaScript to `data: "IDCollection="+sMemberIDCollection+"&task=addnewmember"` and then use the ASP code `task = request.querystring("task")` you will get your results.

Comment: Have you tried alerting "r" in @Arthur P's solution? It may alert you to your problem. `success: function(r) { alert("Returned "+r); }, error: function(r) { alert("Error "+r); }`

Comment: Yeah actually alerting helped debug the problem here was the problem.

Comment: Initially when i poseted, Ajax had a worng syntax which you guys suggested to change and everything. By the time I changed i also changed my original aso from   Request("task")  to Request.querystring("task") and I did not realize that asp is breaking by this time. But now it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should not put quotation marks on keys of your data

```
IDCollection: sMemberIDCollection,
task: "addnewmember"
```

second thing, check with firebug or fiddler if your ajax request is posting right data

Comment: I chekced with the fire bug and Ajax is sending the right data. now I am pretty sure there is something wrowng with the way I am reading with asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this approach also

```
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
 else
    {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
       } 
    var user = document.getElementById("userid").value; 
    var usernm = document.getElementById("username").value; 
    var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value; 
    var ath = document.getElementById("authority").value; 
    var email = document.getElementById("emailid").value; 
    var params = "user=" + user + "&usernm=" + usernm + "&pwd=" + pwd + "&ath=" + ath + "&email=" + email; 
       xmlhttp.open("POST","admin_fans.asp",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.send(params);
```

in this you can send values and store response in some control (in my example in 'results' div i am storing)

Comment: Actually the problem here is that I am supposed to use AJAX here. so cant use Hidden controls or DIVs as carriers.

Comment: no we are not using DIV as carrier its for storing response from the request. We are using 'XMLHttpRequest' to send ajax request